# Stumped on IF statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I can only let the user upload a certain amount of pictures so I am trying to increment a variable 'j' three times before disabling the upload picture button. I know j is incrementing because I printed it out in an alert box for each increment. I really want to know how this is not working. if you have a more elegant solution I am happy with that too.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>


    </style>

</head>
<body>



    <input id="browse" type="file" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple>
    <div id="preview"></div>


    <script>
        var j = 0;

        if (j < 3){

            function previewFiles() {

                j++;
                alert(j);
                var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
                var files   = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

                function readAndPreview(file) {

                    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
                        if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                                var image = new Image();
                                image.height = 100;
                                image.title = file.name;
                                image.src = this.result;
                                preview.appendChild( image );
                            }, false);

                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }

                }

                if (files) {
                    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            alert("I want to get in here");
            document.getElementById("browse").disabled = true;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` block is outside of your function, so when `previewFiles` is called, the `if` block is not executed. Try this:

```js
var j = 0;

function previewFiles() {

    if (j < 3) {


        j++;
        alert(j);
        var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
        var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

        function readAndPreview(file) {

            // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
            if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.height = 100;
                    image.title = file.name;
                    image.src = this.result;
                    preview.appendChild(image);
                }, false);

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

        }

        if (files) {
            [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
        }


    } else {
        alert("I want to get in here");
        document.getElementById("browse").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>


    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <input id="browse" type="file" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple>
    <div id="preview"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Better put `j++;
        alert(j);` below `if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {` to make sure there's only 3 images.